# Слайдер изображений для сайта в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, слайдер

Делаю собственный слайдер изображений без сторонних плагинов на JQUERY и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Если на странице более одного элемента, то слайдер начинает вести себя некорректно.
Код слайдера:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var slideNow = 0;
        var slideCount = $('#portfolio-project-1.portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').children().length;
        var navBtnId = 0;
        var translateWidth = 0;

        $('#portfolio-project-1.portfolio_slider .viewport').hover(
            function () {
                $('.slider_btns').css({'opacity' : '1', 'transition' : 'all ease 0.3s'});
            },
            function () {
                $('.slider_btns').css('opacity','0');
            });
        $('.slider_arrow').click(function() {
            $(".slider_wrap .slide,.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn").removeClass("active");
            $(".slider_nav .slider_nav_btn:eq(" + $(this).addClass("active").index() + ")").addClass('active')
        });
        $(".slider_nav .slider_nav_btn:eq(" + $(".slider_wrap .slide").index() + ")").addClass('active')

        $('.next_btn').click(function() {
            nextSlide();
        });
        $('.prev_btn').click(function() {
            prevSlide();
        });

        $('.slider_nav_btn').click(function() {
            $('.slider_nav_btn').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            navBtnId = $(this).index();

            if (navBtnId + 1 != slideNow) {
                translateWidth = -$('#portfolio-project-1.portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * (navBtnId);
                $('#portfolio-project-1.portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
                    'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                });
                slideNow = navBtnId + 1;
            }
        });

        function nextSlide() {

            slideNow = (slideNow == slideCount - 1) ? 0 : ( slideNow + 1 );
            translateWidth = -$('#portfolio-project-1.portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * ( slideNow );
            $('#portfolio-project-1.portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
                'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
            });


            $('.slider_nav_btn').removeClass('active');
            $('.slider_nav_btn').eq(slideNow).addClass('active');
        }


        function prevSlide() {
            slideNow = (slideNow == 0) ? (slideCount - 1) : slideNow - 1;
            translateWidth = -$('#portfolio-project-1.portfolio_slider .viewport').width() * ( slideNow );
            $('#portfolio-project-1.portfolio_slider .slider_wrap').css({
                'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
                '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
            });
            $('.slider_nav_btn').removeClass('active');
            $('.slider_nav_btn').eq(slideNow).addClass('active');
        }

    });
```

```css
.portfolio_slider {
  width: 100%;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 250px;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% * 5);
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.01, 0.23, 1);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.01, 0.23, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.01, 0.23, 1);
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide {
  width: calc(100%/5);
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap .slide .slide_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap,
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap ul,
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_wrap li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn,
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CD1F40;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn:hover,
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn {
  left: 20px;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn {
  right: 20px;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .prev_btn:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  content: '\f053';
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns .next_btn:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  content: '\f054';
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.portfolio_slider .viewport .slider_btns:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider_nav {
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
.slider_nav .slider_nav_btn.active img {
  border: 3px solid #CD1F40;
}
.slider_nav:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="remodal portfolio_modal" data-remodal-id="portfolio-project-1">
    <div class="project_modal title"><span>Заголовок</span></div>
    <div id="portfolio-project-1" class="portfolio_slider">
        <div class="viewport">
            <ul class="slider_wrap">
                <li class="slide active"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x150?text=Main Image 1" alt="1" class="slide_img"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x150?text=Main Image 2" alt="2" class="slide_img"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x150?text=Main Image 3" alt="3" class="slide_img"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x150?text=Main Image 4" alt="4" class="slide_img"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x150?text=Main Image 5" alt="5" class="slide_img"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="slider_btns">
                <div class="prev_btn slider_arrow"></div>
                <div class="next_btn slider_arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider_nav">
        <div class="slider_nav_btn active"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x75?text=Thumbnail Image 1" alt="1" class="slide_img_thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="slider_nav_btn"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x75?text=Thumbnail Image 2" alt="2" class="slide_img_thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="slider_nav_btn"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x75?text=Thumbnail Image 3" alt="3" class="slide_img_thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="slider_nav_btn"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x75?text=Thumbnail Image 4" alt="4" class="slide_img_thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="slider_nav_btn"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x75?text=Thumbnail Image 5" alt="5" class="slide_img_thumbnail"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Так вот суть в том, что если добавить второй элемент на эту же страницу с id="portfolio-project-2" и добавить его в скрипт слайдера, то слайдер ведет себя некорректно, после пятого изображения дальше листает пустую страницу. Я так понимаю он учитывает все изображения в рамках этого слайдера и пытается их пролистать.

Задача, чтобы эти проекты листались независимо друг от друга. Помогите разобраться :)

Comment: Сейчас так много слайдеров, что хватит на все случаи жизни и с разным функционалом.
У меня возникает вопрос - **Зачем писать свой**? (если это тестовое задание, вопрос не актуален)

Comment: Во-первых, все слайдеры используют кучу различного кода, что для моей задачи не оптимально. Мне вполне хватает того, что я смог реализовать
Во-вторых, я все стараюсь делать сам и крайне редко прибегаю к, различного рода, JQuery плагинам.
В третьих, Спасибо что оповестили о наличии огромного количества слайдеров на все случаи жизни, но это не мой случай.

Comment: чтобы можно было добавить второй слайдер, надо, чтобы ваш код выполнялся в контексте какого-нибудь контейнера, например выбирая `$('.slider_nav_btn')`, надо, чтобы он выбирался внутри одного слайдера, а не всей страницы `$('.slider_nav_btn', slider)`

Comment: Так и не разобрался - что вы имели ввиду? Я добавил общий класс для контейнера со слайдером, но пришел к тому, что нужно как-то отдельно инициализировать активный. Вопрос по-прежнему актуален